# Pass the selected row DataKeyName to a string in a JQuery Modal

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a c# Grdiview, which contains an Hyperlink in the first col. when the user clicks the link, I need the following to happen.

1) Obtain the DataKey Name of the row selected and pass this to a method (code behind), which will build the neccessary data to show in the Model.

2) Present the Model with the data built.

So, I have the Model working, in the sense that I can present a empty one, but I know need assistance with the rest.

I have the following function which doesn't display the value I need

```
    $(function () {
        $('.view-details').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#myModal').modal();
            $('#ticket-id').text("Ticket id: " + $(this).children('td').eq(0).text());
        });
        $('#ticket-tabs a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');
        })
        $('#ticket-tabs a:first').tab('show');
    });

 EDIT  <Columns> 
            <asp:TemplateField>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Hyperlink href="#" data-id="1" class="view-details" runat="server">View details</asp:Hyperlink></td>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>     
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message Id">

         .
         .
        </Columns>
```

Once I have the Id, I can then progress trying to populate the data to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually got to what i neede for the DataKeyName using this method instead.

```
 $('#ticket-id').text("Ticket id: " + $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(1).html());
```

this just gets the second value 'eq(1)' which is the Id, but being displayed in the table.